# File open issue, after file deleted. fopen status is failing in VC++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

fopen example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE * pFile;
    for(int i=0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        bool ret = remove("C:\\abc.txt");
        pFile = fopen ("C:\\abc.txt","w");
        if (pFile!=NULL)
        {
            fputs ("fopen example",pFile);
            fclose (pFile);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d fopen() fails \n", count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, after remove is called, pFile = fopen ("C:\abc.txt","w");is called,

Sometimes even in C:\ the abc.txt file is not present after remove called, but the fopen pFile pointer is null.

This is reproduced some times not always. In this example this issue is reproduced 50/60 times.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Have you tried to check the errno variable? It may be set by the system to some error code which may help you with this issue, you may use perror to gather more information. Have also a look at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html

Comment: Looks like a race condition. Possible optimisations in underlying file system could let `remove` return before everything is really cleared and immediate creation of file with same name breaks. Try to add a short sleep between the remove and the create : it should work.

Comment: remove the file if you want to file open in "w" mode, I think as you do not need.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have already tried with Sleep and it works fine. But in my original application I may not be able to use Sleep. The above code is a test application which proves that fopen fails sometimes and because of this fopen issue my original application fails.
Is there any workaround other than using sleep?

Comment: Deleting a file does not necessarily remove the file from the disk.  What you see is consistent with, say, having anti-malware or a search indexer running on the machine.  Which jumps into action when you create the file, surely a very short time before you start running the program.  Such software opens the file with delete sharing, trying to minimize the impact it has on other programs.  So your remove() call appears to work just fine (even though you never actually check) but the file isn't gone.  You can make it more resilient by renaming the file first, that isn't blocked.

Comment: Dont bother to remove the file.  Just fopen with "w" mode and the file pointer(and associated file length) will be set back to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already established that is is a problem of race condition in the underlying file system, the correct way to fix it is (as suggested by BLUEPIXY) to simply remove the `remove` call :

```
pFile = fopen ("C:\\abc.txt","w");
```

will create the file if it does not exist and truncate it to 0 size if it exists, what is exactly what you need.

Comment: I am using a wrapper function in which fopen call is given. In that if the file is removed it will be opened in write mode otherwise in rb+ mode. So in the case in which it should be removed and again created, the issue occurs.
Also I checked the return value of remove() function to confirm if the remove was successful, to my surprise, I found that sometimes remove returns successful value and further fopen fails giving "Permission denied" as error and sometimes remove() function fails but fopen is successful.
remove() seems to be unreliable function.

Comment: @Aakash : `remove` is not by itsel an unreliable function. But under Windows, it fails if called on an open file (except special access mode), so you have the same race problem. IMHO you should re-think your algorithm to not to do the remove call. *In your use case conditions* it is unsafe.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will check for some other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a file surely after the file was removed, you can delay the fopen until you confirm that the old "abc.txt" file removed.

For that you need to introduce some loop to confirm it like below,

```
bool ret = remove("C:\\abc.txt");
FILE * rFile;
while(true)
{
    rFile = fopen ("C:\\abc.txt","r");
    if(rfile == null)
       break; //File Removed confirmed!!
    else
       sleep(100); //Loop around again...
}
pFile = fopen ("C:\\abc.txt","w");
if (pFile!=NULL)
```